# Android bluetooth socket .connect() error

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

here is my code:

```
Thread connectThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    boolean gotuuid = btDevices.getItem(position)
                            .fetchUuidsWithSdp();
                    if (gotuuid){
                        UUID uuid = btDevices.getItem(position).getUuids()[0]
                                .getUuid();
                        mbtSocket = btDevices.getItem(position)
                                .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

                        mbtSocket.connect();
                    } else {
                        Log.e("ID22", "There is no uuid");
                    }


                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    runOnUiThread(socketErrorRunnable);
                    try {
                        mbtSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
// e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mbtSocket = null;
                    return;
                } finally {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            finish();

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        connectThread.start();
    }
```

When I try to use `mbtSocket.connect();`to connect to the bluetooth soccket it stops and throws `socketErrorRunnable` exception. Have you got any idea how to fix this? I searched about that but nothing works for me.

Comment: can you post the detailed error log on this exception ?

Comment: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1


its not printing exeption, just going in catch statement

Comment: the device you attempt to connect to is either not in range or turn off or unreachable. In the last case, it is mostly because the UUID use in the RFCOMM connexion is either incorrect or does not correspond to a registered service inside the bluetooth of the targetted device. What is the targetted device by the way ?

Comment: I try to send text msg via bluetooth to other android phone with lollipop android. The problem is the same on all devices. I got the device uuid and the bluetooth is turned on the phones are on the same table :)

Comment: Oh I see. You are working on a similar application I was working with except that I am doing this between an Android Phone and a Windows machine. Anyway, that makes thing a lot simplier. If you wrote the app that receives the SMS from the phone, use the same UUID you defined server-side. No need to look for with SPD but it should show up in the btdevice UUIDS and also make sure the bluetooth server you created is turned on ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have troubles here are some code from the official [Android Bluetooth Chat](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat) example :

Server side :

```
public class BluetoothServer {
    private final static String TAG = "BluetoothServer";
    private final BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;

    // I would recommand defining a secure connexion so forget the unsecore UUID
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
            UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66"); // choose another UUID go to a site that generates a random UUI ;-)
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66"); // choose another UUID go to a site that generates a random UUI ;-)
    // BUT THIS WILL BE THE UUID YOU NEED TO CONNECT TO IN YOUR CLIENT APP -> createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("0800200c9a66"));
    // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
    private static final String NAME_SECURE = "BluetoothChatSecure";
    private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "BluetoothChatInsecure";

    public BluetoothServer(BluetoothAdapter adapter, boolean secure) {
        try {
            if (secure) {
                this.serverSocket = adapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                        MY_UUID_SECURE);
            } else {
                this.serverSocket = adapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                        NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + (secure ? "secure" : "insecure") + "listen() failed", e);
        }
    }

    public void asyncStartServer() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final BluetoothSocket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // blocks/wait until your phone connects
                    // at this point, your phone is connected
                    final InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                    // and now start reading
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    Log.getStackTraceString(ioe);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```